# Jquery validate if radiobutton option is yes

Tags: jquery, radio-button, validation

I'm trying to only validate a textfield when a user selects yes. If the option is no then the textfield should not be validated(and it's hidden also).

The validation is done with the validate plugin from www.bassistance.de

Anyone can help me out? I made a fiddle to clarify.

http://jsfiddle.net/logistef/PaTJ4/27/

Comment: try to add the 
var validator = $('yourinput').validate();
after the show

Comment: I have over 70 inputvalues on my form, this is just a small part of it. If I would add it after the .show then the rest of the validation would work inproperly.

I need the actual validate method rule.

Comment: Can you please tidy up your fiddle a little?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the `depends` option in the validate API. Something akin to this should work for you:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    required: {
        depends: function(el) {
            return $("#radio_Yes").attr('checked');
        }
    }
});
```

Here's an updated fiddle with it working: http://jsfiddle.net/PaTJ4/31/

I've also taken the liberty of tidying up your code a little.

Comment: Hey, I knew it had something to do with the depend but I didnt know how to get it working. Thanks for making the fiddle thanks to that I understand it now.

A thousands thanks :D